# Resharper unreachable code error

Tags: resharper

I have read about that error but it was 3 years ago! ReSharper says the inner if statement code is unreachable. Is there any patch to this error?

```
int[] t = new int[1000];
if(t!=null)
{
     if(t[0] ==2)
     {

     }   
}
```

Comment: can you dumb it down for me? You set the array to null and then instantly say "if not null"... presumably nothing has a chance to set it to anything other than null... I would think that resharper is correct...

Answer (score 5):

From the code you've posted, the inner `if` statement is indeed unreachable, since the outer `if` always evaluates to `false` (`t` is always `null`).